# Юнит тестирование приложения при кросс-компиляции

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, тестирование

Я разрабатываю консольное C++ приложение для MIPS роутера. Сборка с помощью кросс-тулчейна. Соответственно, нет возможности запускать юнит-тесты на локальной машине. Для тестирования использовать собираюсь Boost Test.
Вопрос в том, как правильно организовать сборку и запуск юнит-тестов?
У меня два варианта:
- Создание отдельной цели в мейкфайле. будет собираться такой же бинарник, только у него будет другой main.cpp
- Включение всех тестов в сбоку с помощью условий препроцессора. Ну и потом запуск тестов через
./application tests

Как вы тестируете такого рода приложения?

Я, конечно, пользуюсь IDE, но сборка всё равно через Makefile. Так что всякие плагины к IDE точно не подойдут.

UPD: Я понял, что после хорошей декомпозиции, на локальной машине можно делать почти все юнит-тесты, а на целевое железо вынести тесты функциональные, которые будут запускаться при вызове программы с параметром, как описано выше.

Comment: К сожалению, кросс-платформенный код не получится. Там даже libc нет нормального, вместо неё uClibc, которая слегка отличается от стандартной, особенно, что касается с++11. Разве что, отдельные модули можно протестировать. А так, используется специфичное железо на роутере и взаимодействие с ним.

Comment: @victor_crimea, позвольте с Вами не согласиться. До определенного уровня абстракции от конкретного железа *всегда можно написать кроссплатформенный код* (по крайней мере на чистом Си) и тесты на локальной машине. Вопрос лишь в уровне этих абстракций, т.е. какие функции железа Вы будете моделировать "заглушками" (ну, и соответственно сложность этих "заглушек" (или, если угодно, макета железа)).

Comment: Это у вас случаем не [Байкал-Т1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baikal-T1)?

Comment: Нет. Железо [TP-link tl-wdr3600](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_TL-WDR3600)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем тактика простая здесь, код для тестирования писать кроссплатформенным, тестировать и на земле и на железке. Вся надежда на то, что Си будет вести себя одинаково.

Процесс примерно такой:

1. Разработку и тестирование выполняет на рабочей платформе, как можно больше кода выносим в кросплатформенную часть.
2. Периодически выполняем тестирование на целевом вычислителе, при этом результаты тестов на целевой и рабочей платформах должны точно совпадать. В идеале код тестов должен быть одним и тем же.
3. Платформозависимые части должны быть максимально простыми, ошибки в них должны легко находится.

Организация сборки зависит от среды разработки. Вполне может быть что тестирование выполняется на "Виндоуз" и тесты собираются и выполняются студией, при этом целевая платформа может быть лысым чертом с рогами. В этом случае приходится вести два отдельных сборочных проекта, каждый под свой набор инструментов.

Если у вас один и тот же инструмент все собирает, то можно воспользоваться его возможностями для разделения на модули. Ваш вариант с отдельными целями вполне рабочий.